# Autofill textboxes from a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form called frmReferrals that has three text boxes bound to fields on a table called tblReferrals.

I’m trying to use a listbox called List_HRPO to autofill the three textboxes.

The source for the listbox is three columns from a table called tblStudies.

I want the user to click on a row in the listbox and auto fill the three text boxes.

I also need those values to be written to frmReferrals.

```vb
Private Sub List_HRPO_Click()
    Me.hrpo_number = Me.List_HRPO.Column(0)
    Me.hrpo_short_title = Me.List_HRPO.Column(1)
    Me.ccir_number = Me.List_HRPO.Column(2)
End Sub
```

With the textboxes bound to the table, when I click on a listbox row I get:

> “Run-time error '-2147353567 (80020009)': Cannot enter value into
> blank field on 'one' side of outer join”

I’m not basing anything off a query, so I don’t understand where this “outer join” is.

I can avoid the error by unbinding the textboxes. The textboxes auto fill as expected, but the values in the textboxes aren’t written to the table.

Comment: Are you sure form is not bound to a query? Why are you duplicating data in multiple tables?

Comment: Sometimes the definitions of the text fields are mini queries. Enter the fields again

Answer (score 0):

I think, error occurs in this code **Me.hrpo_number = Me.List_HRPO.Column(0)**
Most likely, field `hrpo_number` is key field (`identity`) of table `tblRefferals`. As a rule, this column cannot be updated by the user - will generated by Access as incremental value in this column, before inserting new record to table (in this case tblRefferals).

```
Private Sub List_HRPO_Click()
    ' comment this row. hrpo_number will be updated on "BeforeInsert" event
    'Me.hrpo_number = Me.List_HRPO.Column(0)
    Me.hrpo_short_title = Me.List_HRPO.Column(1)
    Me.ccir_number = Me.List_HRPO.Column(2)
End Sub
```

Without seeing the database schema, it's hard to say what needs to be changed. Definitely - do not change the identity field in the tables.
Perhaps the value assigned by Access DBMS is quite suitable.

If this is not the case, add three text boxes datasource to question. May be field `ccir_number` is link to another table.